# Is there a shortcut in Eclipse for generating code for decorators?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there was some functionality for generating the skeletons of a decorator from an interface similar to `Generate Setters and Getters`. I would like to create a class from an interface that took an instance of that interface and implemented every method as calling that same method with those same parameters on the instance. I have an ugly class from a library that I would like to decorate but it has ~50 methods and I only want to change the functionality of one of them and would like to save some typing. Is there anything like this?

Example, given the interface:

```
 interface FooBar{
      void foo( Object o );
      Object bar();
 }
```

produce something like the class:

```
 class FooBarDecorator implements FooBar{
      private final FooBar fubee;

      FooBarDecorator( final FooBar fb ){
           this.fubee = fb;
      }

      public void foo( Object o ){
           this.fubee.foo( o );
      }

      public Object bar(){
           return this.fubee.bar();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes!! Right click on your `fubee` member, select `Source` -> `Generate Delegate Methods` -> done! Although, I think that for this to work, you will have to write

```
class FooBarDecorator implements FooBar {
// [...]
```

Letting the decorator implement the interface

Comment: Took longer to type that for you to answer. "Delegate Methods" didn't jump out at me as being that until you mentioned it, but now that you mentioned it "duh!". Thanks.